# How do I access the field of a class when the field name is in a variable?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

If I have the name of an object's field stored in a variable, in this case var, how I do I access that field in an object? I assume I should be using %s, but I don't know how to structure the syntax.

```
class object:
    name = "object_name"
var = "name"

print object."%s" % var #causes error
```

I want it to print `"object_name"` but it is causing a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use getattr:

```
getattr(object, var)
```

Anyways, just an additional comment that you are not referencing *object* variables, you are referencing *instance* variables. If you want an instance variable, you need to do something like this:

```
# Note: object is reserved, it's the built-in base class for new-style classes
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'name'

myobj = MyObject()
getattr(myobj, 'name')
```

But getattr doesn't care - classes or instances, they are both Python objects, it works the same way.

Comment: I think you need a `s/object/instance/g` on your post.  Classes are objects.

Answer (score 3):

Use [getattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
getattr(myobject, var)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `getattr` (by the way, these are called *attributes* not fields).  It will work at the class level and the instance level, as shown below.

```
>>> class Foo:
...     attr = 'potato'
...     
>>> getattr(Foo, 'attr')
'potato'
>>> getattr(Foo(), 'attr')
'potato'
```

*Note:* It's best not to name your class `object`, you're shadowing a built-in.